# Convert int to hex string need a better way

Tags: java, int, hex, type-conversion

I am doing a method that can convert a int number to hexadecimal string. Basically my code is work for all test, but I am still looking for an efficient way to get rid of the array part. Anyone would give me a hand?
the better way for not using array, but rather use a string type would be more efficient, and the answer is very clear as above. So i just delete my original code

Comment: @pinckerman if the array is not allowed, what other way i could do?

Comment: A string "0123456789ABCDEF"? In this case you should compare char, but this seems a stupid other way.

Comment: @pinckerman i think this would be a good way. Can you give more details? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";

output = digits.charAt(remain) + output;
```

I hope there are no convertion problems.

Comment: Well, if you notice, the digits[remain] will get an error, since digits is not an array rather a string..

Comment: Java doesn't allow that? In many languages `String`s are nothing but arrays of `char`, and that statement is correct. Try `digits.charAt(remain)`.

Comment: De nada, the concept is the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer.toHexString(int);
```

Should be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I am looking for. I don't want to use any java library, but instead I want to write my own code. Now I just need get rid of array part. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @JavaLeave cant your look into the code of `Integer.toHexString(int)` method

Comment: @Jayamohan well, if i am not wrong `char[] buf = new char[32];` is an array, right?

Comment: Yes its an array only.

Comment: @Jayamohan there should be have another way to do this conversion. I don't believe we have to rely on array

Answer (score 0):

I Think the Integer.toHexString(int) is the best way to fix your problem